# Pruning did not reduce the inference time or model size?

Tags: tensorflow

I ran the pruning [demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning) provided by tensorflow and found that pruning did not reduce the inference time or model size.

Below is my experiment result. It can be seen that the different pruning stages have the same model size.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M May 27 06:15 model.ckpt-2437.data-00000-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.2M May 27 06:15 model.ckpt-2437.data-00001-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K May 27 06:15 model.ckpt-2437.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 368K May 27 06:15 model.ckpt-2437.meta
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M May 27 06:25 model.ckpt-4871.data-00000-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.2M May 27 06:25 model.ckpt-4871.data-00001-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K May 27 06:25 model.ckpt-4871.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 368K May 27 06:25 model.ckpt-4871.meta
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M May 27 06:35 model.ckpt-7329.data-00000-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.2M May 27 06:35 model.ckpt-7329.data-00001-of-00002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K May 27 06:35 model.ckpt-7329.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 368K May 27 06:35 model.ckpt-7329.meta
```

The model inference time obtained in different pruning stages is basically the same.

```
2018-05-27 06:16:42.845279: precision @ 1 = 0.697, inf time = 0.03076
2018-05-27 06:27:26.517855: precision @ 1 = 0.756, inf time = 0.02980
2018-05-27 06:37:31.223502: precision @ 1 = 0.783, inf time = 0.02989
```

I use the default pruning parameters.

Comment: I am curious to know if you found the work around?